# Calculate largest width of a set of elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a quick Jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ujabew/edit#javascript,html,live

What i'm trying to achieve is to find out which is the largest `<section>` out of the 3 from the link. So what i'd like is to, after the loop runs, is to have `var width` set to the largest possible number that any of the widths could be.

Code in progress posted in link

Comment: Insteading of just adding the widths, keep track of the max width found so far. `var max = 0; loop( if this.width > max then max = this.width);` in bad pseudo-code.

Comment: @MarcB That's pretty good psuedo code to me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here:

```
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply( null, $( elems ).map( function () {
    return $( this ).outerWidth( true );
}).get() );
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rM4UG/

Comment: Nice one. When I used this, it was for elements just inside the body that had margin: auto (for centering purposes). If you're doing something similar in IE (standards mode), remove the true being passed into the `outerWidth` function to remove margins from the calculation and you're golden!

Answer (score 3):

Fleshing out Marc B's comment, using `Math.max()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxWidth = 0;
  $('.content ul li').each(function(){
    var itemWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
    maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, itemWidth)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to look into the [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#max) library. Specifically, the max method

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var maxWidth = 0;
  $('section').each(function(){
    w = $(this).outerWidth(true);      
    if ( w > maxWidth)
            maxWidth = w;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `.each()` loop to this:

```
var thisWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);

if (thisWidth > width) {
    width = thisWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my idea:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var elements = $(".content ul li");
  var count = elements.length - 1;
  var width = [];

  elements.each(function (n) {
    width.push($(this).outerWidth(true));
    if (count == n) {
      width = Math.max.apply(Math, width);
    }
  });
});
```

I added the count of the number of elements and then runs the `Math.max` to get the largest number when each loop is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a function regarding this. I thought it might help others. (**jQuery**)

```
$.fn.largerWidth = function () {    //function(p)  
                                    // where 'p' can be clientWidth or offsetWidth 
                                    // or anything else related to width or height
    var s = this,m;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var w = s[i].offsetWidth;   // s[i][p]; 
        (!m || w > m) ? (m = w) : null
    }
    return m;
}
```