# Align text on \t, colon and \t

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following raw text that I wrap in a `<pre>` tag to salvage as much of the *layout* as possible:

```
<pre>

test

field 1 :   Foo
longer field 2  :   Bar
very long field 3   :   FooBar

other text and values

</pre>
```

The field and values are separated by a tab char (\t) a colon and a tab char(\t).

I would like to align the colons so the rendered result would be:

```
test

field 1             :       Foo
longer field 2      :       Bar
very long field 3   :       FooBar

other text and values
```

You'll find a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jvefv8bp/) with my effort so far.

I don't have much control over the text but I tried to replace the \t:\t with a `<span>` so I get some control with css styling but so far not much joy.

This is the javascript I use to replace the \t:\t with a span:

```js
$('pre').html(
        $('pre')
        .html()
        .split('\t:\t')
        .join('<span class="tab">&nbsp;:&nbsp;</span>'));
```

and added this css rule to float the `<span>` but that

```
.tab {
    background-color:red;
    width: 10em;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
}
```

renders the `span` at the start of each new line. I've tried also `position: absolute` to no avail.

What are my options to get the colons aligned?

Comment: I would add span to the text before and after the colons, and then you can have more control over it. Aligning everything after that would be very easy :)

Comment: Hmmm, let me give that a try...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using CSS as the primary driver:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('pre').html(
        $('pre')
        .html()
        .replace(/(.*)\t:\t(.*)/g,function(_,key,value) {
            return '<div class="row">'+
                '<span class="col">'+key+'</span>'+
                '<span class="col"> : </span>'+
                '<span class="col">'+value+'</span>'+
            '</div>';
        })
    );
});
```

```css
pre {display:table}
.row {display:table-row}
.col {display:table-cell}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
    
    test
    
    field 1 : Foo
    longer field 2 : Bar
    very long field 3  : FooBar
    
    other text and values
    
    </pre>
```

The important thing here is that the JavaScript will scan for lines of the required format (`key[tab]:[tab]value`) and dress them up in suitable elements. The CSS then makes them uniform.

Answer (score 9):

Okay, so this was actually a pretty fun one to suss out.

## [Example fiddle with dynamic width](http://jsfiddle.net/jvefv8bp/4/)

Here's what we're doing:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = $('pre').html().split('\n');
    for (var i=0,l=arr.length;i<l;i++){
        if (arr[i].indexOf(':') > -1) {
            var pieces = arr[i].split(':');
            arr[i] = "<span class='left'>" + pieces[0] + "</span>: " + pieces[1];
        }
    }
    
    $('pre').html(arr.join("\n"));
    var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, $('.left').map(function () {
        return $(this).outerWidth(true);
    }).get());
    $('.left').css('width', maxWidth + 15);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

## Explanation of JavaScript

We're separating your `pre` based on the line instead of the colon, here:

```
var arr = $('pre').html().split('\n');
```

Then we're iterating over that looking for a `:` to separate:

```
if (arr[i].indexOf(':') > -1)
```

If we find one, we know that we need to do our super-fancy custom alignment.  We do that by splitting on the `:` and then wrapping the left side in a `span`, like so:

```
var pieces = arr[i].split(':');
arr[i] = "<span class='left'>" + pieces[0] + "</span>: " + pieces[1];
```

Then, we add the modified HTML back to the `pre` and run this fancy little calculation to find the widest piece:

```
var maxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, $('.left').map(function () {
  return $(this).outerWidth(true);
}).get());
```

*Stolen shamelessly from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853777/2145980)*

Then apply the widest width to each left element plus an additional `15px` of padding at the end.

```
$('.left').css('width', maxWidth + 15);
```

Hope that helps!